# Need to publish feed on All Users Timeline Via Facebook Application they have authorised

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi i am using this code to send the feed to specific user by providing id in $gg_fbid.
is there any way to send the feed via Facebook application and access token to all the users using Facebook Application in PHP SDK.
**yes thats what i want, is that possible or should i make a separate database to store their id**

```
  require_once("fb/facebook.php");

  $gg_fbid='100004012849319';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));


  $attachment = array
 (
 'access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken(),
 'message' => 'This Page is awesome.',
 'name' => 'Must Like It',
 'caption' => 'Dailyjokes',
 'link' => 'http://facebook.com/wtfdailyjokes/',
 'description' => 'Awesome Picture',
 'picture' => 'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=264680606974256&set=a.206648236110827.41772.206637039445280&type=1&relevant_count=1'
 );
 $result = $facebook->api($gg_fbid.'/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're wanting to do. Are you just wanting to post to the feed of every user of your Facebook app?

Comment: yes thats what i want, is that possible or should i make a separate database to store their id .

Comment: If you store the access token for each person who authenticates your app, then you can just use that, as that—when decoded—contains the user's ID. So you can just do a `foreach()` on all access tokens, and do your API call to post to that user's wall.

Comment: thanks,, for the help i got what i want..
but no use of access token as if they already allowed publish_stream.
Via direct api call , i can do that.
 thanks by the way Martin :)

Comment: No problem. Hope you got it sorted. But in my experience, I can post to a user's wall by also including `access_token` as in your example, but an access token belongs to a particular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to directly post to wall of Users Using Facebook Application About any Event or something, Thats Why answering my own Question. Facebook permission publish_stream is necessary for this to work. /

You need to create a Database of users when they use your Application like in my Code

```
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));
$args = array(
    'message'   => 'Your Message to user Wall',
    'link'      => 'http://apps.facebook.com/lxxxxxxxx',
    'caption'   => ' Use this Awesome application or Like this Page.',
    'picture'      => 'http://xxxxx.png',



);
$post_id = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $args);


  define('db_user','username);
  define('db_password','password');
  define('db_host','localhost');
  define('db_name','database name');

  // Connect to MySQL
  $dbc = @mysql_connect (db_host, db_user, db_password) OR die ('Could not connect to  MySQL: ' . mysql_error() );
    // Select the correct database
   mysql_select_db (db_name) OR die ('Could not select the database: ' . mysql_error() );


  $me = $facebook->api('/me'); 

        $dbcheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE oauth_provider = 'facebook' AND     oauth_uid = ". $me['id']);  
 $dbr = mysql_fetch_array($dbcheck);  

if(empty($dbr)){ 

  $db=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username) VALUES ('facebook', {$me['id']}, '{$me['name']}')  ");

}
```

SO posting my original Code to tell you in Detail.

This is code when person first opens your application, this $args gets posted to user wall and the id and username is stored to the Database.

SO in the future if anything you want to post to users wall who are using your application and also granted the permission.You can do like promoting website or Facebook Fan Page.

Last how this really happened. As Mr Martin is saying we will need 10 access token for 10 users but thats not correct if your are posting from application than Application token is used to post on all users wall at a time , So with a single access token of Application you can post to million users if your apps has that. SO how to get that access token of application using this link

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=xxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

After that fetch all ids in array and execute the same code to post on all users wall using for loop or anyway still i give my code which i used.

```
<?php 

 require_once("fb/facebook.php");

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));


$x=array("100001944919003","100000968648478","100001672538252","100003924282886");

$y=0;


while($y<=3){

     $posting_fbid=$x[$y];

     $attachment = array
 (
 'access_token'=>'access token from the url from the graph api',
 'message' => 'This Page is awesome.',
 'name' => 'DailyJokes-Must Like It',
 'caption' => 'Dailyjokes',
 'link' => 'http://facebook.com/wtfdailyjokes/',
 'description' => 'Awesome Picture',
 'scope' => 'publish_stream',
 'picture' => 'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=264680606974256&set=a.206648236110827.41772.206637039445280&type=1&relevant_count=1'
 );

  $result = $facebook->api($posting_fbid.'/feed/','post',$attachment);

    echo 'successful for id '.$posting_fbid.'<br>';

    $y++;

}


  ?>
```

Comment: Abhishek Gahlot thank you but there's a problem with your first code .. Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /home/megapixe/public_html/quran/facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1243 ??

Answer (score 1):

If you have a database of access tokens, you can retrieve them and iterate over them to post on your app users' walls.

```
<?php
// instantiate Facebook SDK with your app's credentials
// do database query; fetch access tokens and store in an array called $access_tokens;

foreach ($access_tokens as $access_token) {
    try {
        $facebook->api('/me/feed', array(
            'access_token' => $access_token,
            'message' => 'This Page is awesome.',
            // and the rest of your details
        ));
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        // an error occurred
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again,, it will really help me a lot. Just have to fetch ids and replace here in foreach statement.

Comment: I don't think you understand. The access token identifies the user, as it's unique to a particular user. So when you post to Facebook, Facebook will decrypt the token and know which user's wall to feed to.

Comment: i understood what you are saying martin,, Access token is not generally important in my case Because the application which i am using is already been granted permission through publish_Stream and through the app id and app secret i can post.
Still access token of the permissions is required.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the authorization flow properly. User comes to your app. App asks for permission, user grants it. At this point, Facebook gives you an access token for *that* user, which you must store. So if ten users authenticate your app, you'll have ten access tokens.

Comment: No @Martin, I am able to post without any users access token.
Just need access token from facebook application i created and i am allowed to post to atleast 100 users who granted permission. With only single access token. It is verified as i have tested on 100 users.

Comment: How? An access token is given to you when a user authenticates your app. That *is* how you authenticate a user.

Comment: From the Graphi API explorer i get the access token of my application by selecting the Permissions used in the Application and that access token is Used for all the users. 
if u need live example i can show it to you

Comment: Really @Martin ,,Want to ask , From single access-token cant we really  not post on Users wall.. but still i have done

Comment: I'm not sure one access token issued from the Graph API Explorer would allow you to post to more that one person's wall on Facebook; that would be open to spam. Anyone could just get an access token and post to people's Facebook walls then.

Comment: Still anyone cant get the list of ID's or secret key of application . Still will give you source Code. for this to work. And you test yourself.

Comment: Can you post a sample of this? I'm interested on how you've achieved it.

Comment: Really i will tell you @Martin.. After few hours. Just busy in some work.